# Why can't Visual Studio find the Node.js runtime installed by the Visual Studio Installer?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

### EDIT

It turns out that the nodejs version installed by Visual Studio, should not be used, but that nodejs should be installed separately. It seems that enabling nodejs for visual studio, just enables the templates. You have to install nodejs yourself. The nodejs version installed by visual studio, is used internally by visual studio, and messing with it may corrupt our visual studio install.

Below follows the original question.

### Here is what I did

1. I installed Node.js with the Visual Studio Installer:

[image: I installed Node.js with the Visual Studio Installer]

2. I closed the installer, opened Visual Studio, closed Visual Studio and rebooted the PC.
3. I searched my Visual Studio installation to see if Visual Studio has installed the Node.js runtime:

[image: Where Visual Studio has installed Node.js]

3. I opened Visual Studio again to create a "Blank Node.js Console Application":

[image: Creating a Blank Node.js Console Application]

4. When I create the project, Visual Studio claims that the Node.js runtime can't be found:

[image: Visual Studio can't find the Node.js installation]

### Question

Why can't Visual Studio find it - is it a bug? I already know how to configure Visual Studio to find it. Should I configure Visual Studio to use the Node.js runtime installed by the Visual Studio Installer?

### Thoughts

- I noticed that the Node.js runtime is not in the path when you start a Visual Studio Developer Command prompt.
- I wonder, if I use the Node.js runtime I found above (update it, add global packages), if it will interfere with the operation of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If Visual Studio doesn't detect your installed runtime (it generally does), configure your project to reference the installed runtime:

This is from Microsoft docs

[Link to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-nodejs)

Comment: I know how to configure Visual Studio to use my Node.js runtime of choice. I have read the docs and searched stackoverflow before I posted. My question is WHY visual studio and the installer fails to do this - is it because the runtime (installed at the location shown in my question), shouldn't be used? Or is it a bug? Or something else?

Comment: It could be a bug maybe. I develop node apps using VS Code so I can't be completely sure about that. I thought configuring Visual Studio manually would solve it

Comment: I ran into this same _"Can't find the Node.js runtime"_ error in VS, and the workaround was to  simply use the Node.js Windows Installer (outside of VS): https://nodejs.org/en/download/.

Comment: @emallove But this will install nodejs twice.

Answer (score 0):

Add the node path installed with VS to the system or user `PATH`:

1. Open the *System Properties* window, click *Environment Variables...*, then select the `Path` variable and click *Edit...*.
   To find that windows search the start menu for *Environment Variables*

   [image]
2. Click *New* and add the following line:
   `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeJs`

   [image]
3. Save all settings and restart machine.

Comment: I write in my question "I already know how to configure Visual Studio to find it.". It turns out that the nodejs version installed by visual studio, should not be used, but that nodejs should be installed separately.

It seems that enabling nodejs for visual studio, just enables the templates. You have to install nodejs yourself.

The nodejs version installed by visual studio, is used internally by visual studio, and messing with it may corrupt our visual studio install.

Comment: I'll keep my answer for the reference, thanks for your useful comment!